# how to encode transaction input data in Golang?

Tags: go-ethereum

### Heading

In the web3j module, the following method can be used to generate input data to send raw transaction by passing the contract function name and parameters.

```
new Function(functionName, argumentList, Collections.<TypeReference<?>>emptyList());
FunctionEncoder.encode(functionCall)
```

I want to know if there is a similar method in Golang, I only have the public and private key of the account, the contract address, and the contract code. There is no abi.json file, I do not know if this can generate input data.

Comment: Golang has abi.JSON (file) and abi.Pack() to generate input data, but this method requires an abi.json file, which I don't have.

Answer (score 0):

```
name := "add"
rawName := "add"
funType := 0
mutability := "view"
param1, err := abi.NewType("value", "int", nil)
inputs := abi.Arguments{
    abi.Argument{
        Name:    "value",
        Type:    param1,
        Indexed: false,
    },
}

method := abi.NewMethod(name, rawName, abi.FunctionType(funType), mutability, false, false, inputs, nil)

input, err := method.Inputs.Pack(1)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

log.Println(common.Bytes2Hex(input))
```

I've seen this method before, but it hasn't worked.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).